# Vertically Center Multi-line SVG Text

Tags: css, svg

Can anyone give me **an example** of how to vertically center multi-line text in SVG? I've googled and I see lots of references to *alignment-baseline* and *dominant-baselin*e, but no concrete example for me to look at.

For example, in the following SVG, the TEXT element is locked by its top left-hand corner. Text starts appearing after that y position. What would I need to do if I wanted the text to be evenly distributed above and below that y position?

```
<text x="110" y="50" dy="0">
   <tspan dy="0em" x="110" style="font-weight: bold; fill: rgb(74, 76, 77);">
     <tspan x="110" dy="0em">This is my long quotation that will now wrap</tspan>
     <tspan x="110" dy="1.1em">over multiple lines, maybe even two lines!</tspan>
     <tspan x="110" dy="1.1em">Isn't that amazing?</tspan>
   </tspan>
   <tspan dy="1.5em" x="110" style="font-style: italic;">
     Speaker, Speaker Description
   </tspan>
</text>
```

(I'm generating this via D3, if that helps)

Comment: Please deliver a picture of now and what you wanna have. That would help much more then reading a text.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do automatic centering with SVG.  SVG has no proper automatic layout.

You can however use `dy`, like you are doing, to position text relative to your baseline.  Remember `dy` can also be negative.

```html
<svg width="400" height="150">

  <line x1="110" y1="50" x2="400" y2="50" stroke="red"/>
  <text x="110" y="50">
     <tspan x="110" dy="-0.8em">This is my long quotation that will now wrap</tspan>
     <tspan x="110" dy="1.1em">over multiple lines, maybe even two lines!</tspan>
     <tspan x="110" dy="1.1em">Isn't that amazing?</tspan>
  </text>

</svg>
```

The other thing you can do is use a `<foreignObject>` element to embed HTML in your SVG.  Obviously that only works in browsers.

Comment: Well, that's disappointing! I can do it manually via Javascript - measuring the text dimensions and then changing the y value appropriately. Thanks :)

Comment: Is that true for even single line pieces of text?

Comment: You can experiment with `alignment-baseline: middle`, but that doesn't work in all cases, and may not give the desired centering when it does.